# Error:Android_HOME is set to non-existant path:

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

When I run this command on Windows 8:

```
c:\firstapp> cordova platform add android
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Error:ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existant path c://android/android-sdk-windows
> ```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in it and how fix it?

Comment: Where is your android SDK? what's the directory?

Comment: SDK is in c drive under android folder

Comment: OP, I have no idea if you ever resolved your problem, but it's one I am encountering now.  It might be a good week before I can revisit this, but one answer talks about an incompatibiltity between the latest Android SDK and Cordova at that time.   And this makes a lot of sense in cases where you have dozens of interacting software packages from different sources.
I am going to explore that possibility when I have time to bang my head on this side project again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216081/android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set/add `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to where your Android-SDK lies (the directory which includes `platform-tools` and `tools` directory). And extend the `PATH` environment variable to include those two directories as well.

In case you installed the sdk to `c:\dev\android\sdk`, then `ANDROID_HOME` must have exactly this path as value.
When editing the `PATH` environment variable, you must add (append) `;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` to it.

[Here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) you can read how to set those variable on a windows system.

Comment: Can the ANDROID_HOME variable handle spaces in the path?  If not, can it handle a tilde shortened path?  Is it expecting a genuine Windows path or do I need to use forward slashes?  Do I need to double-escape my backslashes?  Currently when I execute "dir %ANDROID_HOME%", I see the SDK directory contents including the tools and platform tools directory.  However, when I run "phonegap build android", I get the error message that the OP mentioned.